# Cross-Domain Remoting - Issues determining which credentials to use

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am working on a script that will be running remote PowerShell on a large list of servers, **these servers may randomly change domains**. So, for instance, a list might have 50 servers on domain A and 150 servers on domain B.

I have been successful in executing this script via using wildcards/regex to determine which domain the server is joined to.

That being said, using names is an awful solution, and I would like to find a better way to determine the correct credentials to use. I would like to avoid using `Invoke-Command` just to test the connection. The best solution I have found is to use something akin to the following:

```
try {
    $session = New-PSSession -Credential $a -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    $session = New-PSSession -Credential $b -ComputerName $_
}
```

In this case, `$_` is simply a string, a computer name. The credential objects are defined via `Get-Credential`.

I feel like this could be much more efficient, in theory. Additionally, it simply does not work. While me using if/else with the exact same contents functions perfectly, the code in `catch` always fails with:

> New-PSSession : One or more computer names are not valid.

This does not make much sense to me, since the syntax I use functions perfectly everywhere outside `catch`. For instance, in the above example, the code in `try` works. Swapping the contents of each block still results in failure of `catch`. I have also tried using `Remove-PSSession $session`, however that did not seem to help.

So my question is:

1. Is this even the best way to accomplish this task?
2. If it is, why does my catch block inexplicably fail?

Comment: Use a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) for mapping domain names to credentials? Are the computer names FQDNs? Does a DNS lookup return the correct domain?

Comment: If I had that information, this wouldn't be an issue in the first place. The point is to allow for a certain level of transience.

Comment: Using DNS lookup is a good idea, I will try it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers This worked for me if you would like to submit an answer.

Comment: "*This does not make much sense to me, since the syntax I use functions perfectly everywhere outside catch*" - `$_` works perfectly in a catch scriptblock too, referring to the error that was caught - `try { 1/0 } catch { write-host $_ }`

Comment: Yes, I assume it had to do with the connection object. I am just not certain why it occurs even after removing the object... Oh well, connections are strange and often I just have to find a work around rather than actually fixing it. It's like powershell just hates disposing them properly, I don't know why. Anyway, the DNS solution is better in all cases I think, so I'm willing to just leave that one be...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a DNS lookup to get the FQDN from the hostname, remove the hostname from the FQDN to get the domain name, then lookup the credentials by the domain name in a hashtable.

```
$credentials = @{
    'example.com' = $a
    'example.com' = $b
    ...
}

...

$serverList | ForEach-Object {
    $fqdn = [Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($_) | Select-Object -Expand HostName
    $null, $domain = $fqdn -split '\.', 2
    $cred = $credentials[$domain]

    $session = New-PSSession -Credential $cred -ComputerName $fqdn
    ...
}
```